# Comma as separator in variable initialization (not as operator)

Tags: c++, c, variables, initialization, comma-operator

This seems such a simple question, but something I've not examined for ages in my own style... When initializing variables separated by a comma, I've assumed the following to be an unsafe practice:

`unsigned int n = foo.size, nxn = n * n;`

Since I don't really ever use the comma *operator* as such for syntactic sugar, etc; but rather to indicate that two expressions are independent - as a kind of implicit commentary on 'fine-grained parallelism' (or expression independence), that often makes code a bit more terse, e.g.,

```
if (<some condition>)
    a = true, b = value;
```

rather than requiring `{}` scope for semi-colon separated expressions.

But my question is really in re-examining the variable initialization case. Have I been incorrect in my assumption that `nxn` can't be relied on to be initialized as expected? Or have I been laboring under a misinterpretation all this time?

Comment: When in doubt, always use the safer approach :)

Comment: According to [this declarator reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations#Declarators), the declaration list is fully left-to-right, including initialization. In short, `unsigned int n = foo.size, nxn = n * n;` is equivalent to `unsigned int n = foo.siz; unsigned int nxn = n * n;`

Comment: One possible drawback of using comma is that you can get confused with statement like `int* a, b`. This can look like both variables are of type `int*` but in fact we get `int* a; int b;`

Comment: @grapes - yes. I'm also concerned about readability (I wouldn't take a shortcut like that because it tends to slow a reader down).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per [[dcl.decl]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.decl#3)

> Each *init-declarator* in a declaration is analyzed separately as if it was in a declaration by itself. [...]

we get that

```
unsigned int n = foo.size, nxn = n * n;
```

is the same as

```
unsigned int n = foo.size;
unsigned int nxn = n * n;
```

There is a note with exceptions for other rules like `auto` or if a name shadows the type but those don't apply in this case.

---

Be very wary with pointers if you put multiple variables on a single line

```
int * foo, bar;
```

does not give you two pointers.  Instead, `foo` is a pointer and `bar` is an `int`.  You would need

```
int * foo, * bar;
```

to get two pointers.  For this reason I would prefer to use

```
int * foo;
int * bar;
```

and pay the extra keystorkes for safeties sake.

Comment: I guess if that's the rule, I don't see any ambiguity. In fact, I would *prefer* to use the syntax I gave in the example if that's correct. Would *others* have difficulty discerning the comma as separator, and comma as operator? Any thoughts on style?

Comment: @BrettHale I can't speak for others but I like declaring one variable per line.  The is double true when dealing with pointers.  For instance `int * foo, bar;` doesn't declare two `int*`'s.  Instead `foo` is a pointer and `bar` is just an `int`.  You would need `int * foo, * bar` to get two pointers.  It is for reasons like that I keep them separate.  It also makes removing a variable easier if you need to later on.  I've added this into the answer.

Comment: I'd certainly agree with that. It's just in a current project I've literally provided the case from, where I want to make `n`, `n * n`, etc., of the same type. I find this style more concise. Mixing with pointers - hard to read, bad style.

Comment: @BrettHale You can always use `auto`.  `some_type var1 = some value; auto var2 = var1 * var1; auto var3 = var2 * var1; ...`

Answer (score 3):

`nxn` will be initialized properly, since `n` has been defined and initialized at the point where `nxn` is defined.

For clarity however, it would be better to put the variables on separate lines.  Doing so avoids ambiguity, making your intent more clear to anyone who reads your code.

Comment: +1. Thanks. I'm not sure I agree with the second line for simple cases - but style can be very much a personal thing!

Comment: @BrettHale: I agree with you. I have the luxury of being able to hire the smartest folk possible; my philosophy behind my coding standards are to make use of every feature of the language as appropriate. If the behaviour of `unsigned int n = foo.size, nxn = n * n;` is not obvious to someone at my shop then they need to set some time aside to learn the language. Using separate lines in this case could be dangerous should someone refactor one of the types to `int` and retaining `unsigned` for the other.